# React Recompose : Method created in WithStateProps is not accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recompose

I am using Recompose to define some methods like below :

```
export interface WithStateProps {
  isDisabled: boolean;
  isReady: boolean;
  setDisabled(value: boolean): void;
  setReady(value: boolean): void;
}


export const withStateHoc = withState('isDisabled', 'setDisabled', false);
export const withIsEligibleStateHoc = withState(
  'isReady',
  'setReady',
  true
);

export const isReady = (value : string) => {
  return value ? true : false
};

export type WrappedProps = StepContentProps &
  FormikProps<MyAddress> &
  InjectedIntlProps & 
  AddressFormHandlers & WithStateProps;
```

When I want to use the `setReady` method I get this message: `props.setReady is not a function` Here is my code:

```
export const withFormikHoc = withFormik<
  WrappedProps & RouteComponentProps<{}> & InjectedIntlProps & WithStateProps,
  MyAddress
>({
 handleSubmit: async (values, { props, setSubmitting }) => {
     const addressAlreadyVerified = isReady(values.country);
     if(addressAlreadyVerified) {
        props.setReady(true)
     }
   }
})
```

When I hover on `props.setReady(true)` in VCode, I can see: `(method) WithStateProps.setReady(value: boolean): void`

But I know that `props.setReady` is not a function!

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: Add your that `setReady` where you're using `withFormikHoc`

Comment: Already added by adding : WrappedProps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I find the problem, which was my mistake, in my `compose` I added `withFormikHoc` before `withStateHoc` & `withIsEligibleStateHoc` and that was the reason for the error. After bring them first problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting the props properly. Your deconstructor is wrong.

Here is how it should look:

```
handleSubmit: async (values, { setSubmitting, ...props }) => {
```

What it means: from your component props, extract `setSubmitting` into its own variable and put everything else inside a `props` object.

What you should actually do:

```
handleSubmit: async (values, { setReady, setSubmitting }) => {
  const addressAlreadyVerified = isReady(values.country);
  if (addressAlreadyVerified) {
    setReady(true)
  }
}
```

This way, you only extract the values that you need from your props, and don't end up with an object full of properties you don't really need.

EDIT

If you want, you can choose NOT to deconstruct anything and your could would end up somewhat like this:

```
handleSubmit: async (values, props) => {
  const addressAlreadyVerified = isReady(values.country);
  if (addressAlreadyVerified) {
    props.setReady(true)
  }
}
```

I just realized that you're not using `setSubmitting` at all. You can just remove that if you wish.